# XML response after javascript processed an image - just base64

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, xml

hello I have a big problem and can not get any further.

A function is used to add polygons to an image. After that it is encoded to base64.
Now the client is supposed to request the page and have its image processed and only get the base64 back.

The problem: every time only the source code of the page comes back without even loading the image and providing it with the polygons.

Client Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/polyimg/?size=500',
    typ: 'GET',
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result)
    }
});
```

callback from Server:
`<html> ... </html>`

Instead of:
`data:image/jpeg;base64,...`

I do not know what to do.
Does this work at all?
I have already tried to written the server with NodeJS, but he would send again only the source code.

I've tried with XML to set the request itself, but without success. I've been sitting on this for several hours and hoping for a good answer. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be `http://localhost:port/polyimg` ? If you don't specify the port (`http://localhost/`), the default port will be 80. But probably your dev server doesn't run on port 80, does it?

Comment: no, its just "localhost/polyimg/index.html?size=500"
when Im using nodejs then its running on 8080

Comment: Can you provide the code of your endpoint? GET /http://localhost/polyimg/?size=500